# Ember Addon: writing unit tests for files in my addon folder

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-qunit

I am writing an Ember Addon that provides some services that are not exposed through the **app/** folder.

```
// project Foo
// addon/services/foo.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({})
```

The unit test that gets generated by Ember CLI uses **moduleFor** helper.

```
// tests/unit/services/foo.js
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('service:foo', 'Unit | Service | foo', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  // needs: ['service:foo']
});

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it exists', function(assert) {
  let service = this.subject();
  assert.ok(service);
});
```

Problem is that since my FooService is not exposed through the **app/** folder, *moduleFor* helper cannot find it using **service:foo** name.

What would be the best way to unit test my service here?
I can see three possibilities:

1) add `tests/dummy/app/services/foo.js` that exports FooService

```
// tests/dummy/app/services/foo.js
export { default } from 'foo/services/foo.js';
```

2) create initializers in the dummy app that registers `service:foo`

```
// tests/dummy/app/initializers/account-data.js
import FooService from 'foo/services/foo'
export function initialize(application) {
  application.register('service:foo', FooService);
}
```

> **EDIT**
>   turns out I can't do this. it's not that moduleFor helper is trying to find 'service:foo' but trying to register 'app/services/foo' as 'service:foo'. So registering 'service:foo' ahead of the time does not help.

3) don't use **moduleFor** helper.

> **EDIT** 
>   By this I meant something like what @Andy Pye's answer. But it would be nice to be able to use **moduleFor** helper... Especially for models since I need access to `store`.

**EDIT**
turns out it gets more complicated for models since I can't create them directly. So if I go with not using `moduleFor` helper, I need an instead of `store` object...

Comment: actually turns out I cannot do **2)**... i guess `moduleFor` helper is trying to look up the module and register based on the name and it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same (or a very similar) issue. I've found that this seems to work:

```
// tests/unit/services/foo.js
import { module, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import FooService from 'Foo/services/foo';

module('Unit | Service | foo', {
    // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
    // needs: ['service:foo']
});

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it exists', function (assert) {
    let service = FooService.create();
    assert.ok(service);
});
```

Comment: yup, that's what I meant by **3)**. But it would be nice if I could use the moduleFor helper... but there doesn't seem to be a way other than **1)**

Comment: Agreed, it's not as nice as moduleFor, and I couldn't find it documented anywhere either. I had to poke around some existing addons to find how other people were doing this...

Comment: yeah, I've been doing the same thing but problem is with testing models since they cannot be created on their own. I need to get an instance of `store` and couldn't figure out how to do that